# How can i make a click button when do i click make sort(a-b) array and then click again to sort(b-a)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, togglebutton

Here is my question
How can i make a click button when do i click make array.sort(x-y) and then click again to make array.sort(y-x)

i'm already have the function but i'm confuse how to do it...

let me clarify my question: when do i click on button i make sort to array from bigger to smaller number and then i would like to press on the same button to make the array sort from smaller to bigger

here is my code:

```
$(".lower").click(() => {
    colorsValueMenu("highest", "spot", "gainers", "losers", "lower")
    highest = arrayCoinsD.sort(function (a, b) { return b.quote.USD.percent_change_24h - a.quote.USD.percent_change_24h })
    createCoinDiv(arrayCoinsD, arrayCoinsI)
    $(".lower").click(() => {
        colorsValueMenu("lower", "spot", "gainers", "losers", "highest")
        lower = arrayCoinsD.sort(function (a, b) { return a.quote.USD.percent_change_24h - b.quote.USD.percent_change_24h })
        createCoinDiv(arrayCoinsD, arrayCoinsI)
    })
})
```

it's work but just on the first & second time... i want to make it like toggleClass action for every single click

Comment: You can create a `flag` and according to that flag you can sort it.

Comment: this is my first time hear about flag, can you show me example code for my question pleas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your code `DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)`

You can create a `flag` and change the operations as per the `flag` as:

```
let flag = "high";

$(".lower").click(() => {
  //   Highest
  colorsValueMenu(
    flag === "high" ? "highest" : "lower",
    "spot",
    "gainers",
    "losers",
    "lower"
  );
  highest = arrayCoinsD.sort(function (a, b) {
    return flag === "high"
      ? b.quote.USD.percent_change_24h - a.quote.USD.percent_change_24h
      : a.quote.USD.percent_change_24h - b.quote.USD.percent_change_24h;
  });

  createCoinDiv(arrayCoinsD, arrayCoinsI);
  flag = flag === "high" ? "low" : "high";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing right now is creating an event listener on #lower. This will do the sort(a-b) like you ask, but inside that event listener you are creating another event listener, which isn't going to work. What you can do instead is create a flag like someone in the comments suggested. An example would be:

```
flag = false;
("#lower").click(() => {
    flag = !flag;
    if (flag) {
        //do this thing;
    } else {
        //do this other thing;
    }
}
```

This way, the behavior alternates whenever you click it. You can then use that to sort in different ways.

Comment: good solution, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toggle` method to do ascending and when you click again descending like this:

```
$(".lower").toggle(function(){
    // Ascending code or function
}, function (){
    // Descending code or function
})
```

Check the official reference here: https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/